# Is my code too repetitive?

Tags: java, android

I was working on my text adventure game, and was wondering if there is an easier way to program repetitive blocks of code such as what I have below.

In this block, the user is presented with N,E,S,W for North, East, South, and West.  So I write each listener separately and include a try/catch block in each listener.  But the whole block of code now seems really repetitive.

Here is the block of code:

```
btnNorth.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvIntro.setText("You go north");
            String testString = "nothing";
            try {
                testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            tvIntro.setText(testString);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tvIntro.setText(testString);            
        }
    });

    btnEast.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvIntro.setText("You go east");
            String testString = "nothing";
            try {
                testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            tvIntro.setText(testString);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tvIntro.setText(testString);
        }
    });

    btnSouth.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvIntro.setText("You go south");
            String testString = "nothing";
            try {
                testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            tvIntro.setText(testString);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tvIntro.setText(testString);
        }
    });

    btnWest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvIntro.setText("you go west");
            String testString = "nothing";
            try {
                testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            tvIntro.setText(testString);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tvIntro.setText(testString);
        };
    });
```

Comment: This question should probably be here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create one OnClickListener that all of your buttons will use and in that OnClickListener, you will detect which button was clicked and do direction specific tasks in a switch statement.

Something like this:

```
private OnClickListener DirectionClickListner = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.north:
            //Set your strings for North
            break;
        case R.id.west:
            //Set your strings for West
            break;
        case R.id.east:
            //Set your strings for East
            break;
        case R.id.south:
            //Set your strings for South
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not abstract that into a single function, like this (psuedo-code):

```
btnNorth.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        move("North");          
    }
});
btnSouth.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        move("South");          
    }
});
btnEast.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        move("East");          
    }
});
btnWest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        move("West");          
    }
});

void move(String direction) {
        tvIntro.setText("You go " + direction);
        String testString = "nothing";
        try {
            testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
        tvIntro.setText(testString);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tvIntro.setText(testString);  
}
```

You could certainly clean this up some more, but at least most of the common code is in a single location :)

Comment: That's a nice approach, though you create 4 listener objects, where you could've create one with simple switch case.

Comment: @MByD - I completely agree, I think that BalusC has the most elegant/simplest solution and would recommend using that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You should save the listener that does that same thing as a member variable.

```
private OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() { ... };
```

and use like this.

```
btnNorth.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
btnEast.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
btnSouth.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
```

Comment: How does he pass in specific values for north, south, east and west?

Comment: He can do it like `hooked82`'s answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try encapsulating your game logic in its own class. So each `OnClickListener` would just have an instance of this one class and then they can just call `goEast()` or `goWest()` etc on that one class. This will keep all the logic in a single class and reduce the amount of repetitive code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try test-driven development. If you're always doing the simplest thing, you'll find it easier to refactor your code so that you can avoid repeating yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Modified your example with a OO approach, this makes your code more testable too.

```
static interface DirectionProvider {
    String getDirection();
}

DirectionProvider north = new DirectionProvider() {
    public String getDirection() {
        return "You go north";
    }           
};

DirectionProvider south = new DirectionProvider() {
    public String getDirection() {
        return "You go south";
    }           
};

DirectionProvider east = new DirectionProvider() {
    public String getDirection() {
        return "You go east";
    }           
};

DirectionProvider west = new DirectionProvider() {
    public String getDirection() {
        return "You go west";
    }           
};

static class MyOnClickListener extends OnClickListener {
    public MyOnClickListener(DirectionProvider dp) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvIntro.setText(dp.getDirection());
            String testString = "nothing";
            try {
                testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            tvIntro.setText(testString);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tvIntro.setText(testString);            
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use your new listeners like this:

```
btnEast.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(north));
btnSouth.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(south));
btnWest.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(west));
btnEast.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(east));
```